# FTP Uploads not completing on AWS server (vsftp)

Tags: ftp, amazon-web-services

I have an AWS server that is running vsftp and I don't receive a 226 message that the transfer is complete.  My php editor was showing failed uploads so I watched the transaction using FileZilla and CuteFTP.

- The upload is initiated.
- The file appears on the server.
- No 226 response is received so the FTP manager times out and attempts to restart the upload.
- On restart I am asked to confirm that I want to overwrite the file just uploaded.
- I've tested the uploaded file and the transferred file is complete.

I verified that the FTP manager software is working by uploading to another server in another hosting facility.  (This other computer is running another FTP service.

I am able to successfully list directories, download files, and even create new directories.

I have upgraded vsftp in an attempt to fix the problem.

I've been struggling with this for a while.  Any ideas appreciated.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

After purging vsftp on the server and testing several other conf changes I remotely connected to a PC in another office, loaded FileZilla, and found that there was no problem there.

It turns out that this server needed to be white listed in the local firewall software on PCs in my office running BitDefender Internet Security software under Windows 7.  Why did the Amazon AWS server need to be listed but the other server did not?  Why did only one [server] reply in the FTP transaction get blocked by firewall?  No answers and no time for further testing.  FTP links are running properly for all programs.